# Defining the existence of a non algebraic element in the language $L:= \{0,1,+,\cdot\}$

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

I raise following question after reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393188/language-structure-of-mathbbr-and-l-mathbbr/1393355#1393355).

Is it possible in the language $L:= \{0,1,+,\cdot\}$ to write sentences for which a model will *necessarily* contain a copy of $\mathbb Q$ and a non algebraic element?

If yes, what is this set of sentences? If not can you provide a proof?

Thanks.

*I added the word necessarily to precise the question.*

Comment: That's a bit of an odd question.

Comment: Can you make it contain $\mathbb Z$, even? (I know nothing about model theory)

Comment: @Asaf Why do you say so?

Comment: Because the question can be read as "is there a model", and then the answer is nearly obviously "yes", or "is there a theory", in which case the answer is pretty much "no", assuming you mean something which extends the theory of fields.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why "pretty much 'no'"? Theories of fields can be very complicated...

Comment: @columbus8myhw Any first-order theory containing the field axioms and the statements $\lnot n = 0$ for all $n$ (here $n$ is shorthand for $1+\dots+1$) will force its models to be of characteristic $0$ and hence contain $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @RamiroGuerreiro Your intuition that the ordering on an ordered field can't be defined just from the function symbols $+$ and $\cdot$ is wrong. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, the order $x<y$ is definable by $\exists z\, x+z^2 = y$. The order is also definable from the field language in $\mathbb{Q}$, but this is harder to see. Here's one way (although there might be easier ways): Due to Julia Robinson, there is a first-order formula defining $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. An integer is nonnegative if and only if it's the sum of $4$ squares...

Comment: ... A rational is positive if and only if its the ratio of two positive integers. So we can define the positive rationals by some first-order formula $\varphi_+(z)$. Then the order $x<y$ is definable by $\exists x\, \varphi_+(z) \land (x+z = y)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  I don't see a problema is to go from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. And I agree there is  first-order formula defining $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Sorry, I was not very precise in previous comment.  My intuition is about defining an order, with all necessary  properties to recover  $\mathbb{R}$ topology,  just using first-order logic and  an $L$ as given in the question.   But, may be my intuition is wrong, I didn't really spent time thinking about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking for an $L$-theory $T$, presumably extending the theory of fields, such that every model of $T$ is of characteristic $0$ and hence contains $\mathbb{Q}$ (this is easy) and contains a transcendental element (this is harder).

There are such theories, but analyzing them requires a lot of algebraic work. As a concrete example, let $R$ be the real closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ (its elements are the real numbers which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$). Now consider $R(t)$, the field obtained by adjoining one transcendental $t$. It's a fact that $R$ is definable in $R(t)$. That is, there is a first-order formula $\varphi_R(x)$ in the language of fields such that for all $a\in R(t)$, $R(t)\models\varphi_R(a)$ if and only if $a\in R$.

I can even write down the formula explicitly: $\exists y\, 1+x^4 = y^2$. For a proof that this works, see Proposition 3.3 in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=yMz9fW8JgiwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), noting that every real closed field is Pythagorean (every sum of two squares is non-negative, hence is a square) of characteristic $0$.

Now let $T = \text{Th}(R(t))$. $T$ expresses the following:

1. The set of all elements satisfying $\varphi_R$ is a subfield which is real closed.
2. There is some element not satisfying $\varphi_R$.
3. For every polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ with coefficients satisfying $\varphi_R$, if $a$ does not satisfy $\varphi_R$, then $a$ is not a root of $p$ (this is because $R$ is relatively algebraically closed in $R(t)$).

So any model $K\models T$ has a subfield $\varphi_R(K)$ which is real closed, and hence contains $\mathbb{Q}$, but $K$ also contains elements which are not algebraic over $\varphi_R(K)$, and hence are not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks Alex for taking the time to post this detailed answer. There is one thing that I don't understand. Why $T$ expresses the existence of an element not satisfying $\varphi_R$ - your point number 2.?

Comment: Well, in $R(t)$, there's an element which is not in $R$ ($t$, for example), so $R(t)\models \exists x\, \lnot \varphi_R(x)$, and hence this sentence is in $T$.

Comment: Thanks... I should have seen that!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example, similar to what Alex gave.

Let $T$ be the theory of fields asserting that every nonconstant polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a root, that the charactersitic is zero, and that not every element has a square root. This theory is finitely satisfiable: simply pick a finite field of large characteristic containing the roots of any given collection of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, making sure that the characteristic is also larger than the absolute values of these coefficients.

Every model of this theory will contain $\mathbb{Q}$, since it will be a field of characteristic zero. It will also contain the algebraic clousre of $\mathbb{Q}$, since every polynomial with integer coefficients has a root. However, the field must be bigger than that, since not every element has a square root.

Comment: Nice! This is much simpler - somehow I hadn't thought of only asserting that polynomials with integer coefficients have roots. To make the answer even simpler, you can leave out the compactness argument involving finite fields - $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ is already clearly a model of all of $T$!